# What is the Time complexity of this recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity

```
void rec( char s1[], char s2[], int i,  map< char, int > m1, map< char, int > m2 ) {
    if ( i == n ){
        return;
    }
    rec( s1, s2, i+1, m1, m2 );
    m1[ s1[ i ] ]--;
    if ( m1[ s1[ i ] ] == 0 ){
        m1.erase( s1[ i ] );
    }
    m2[ s2[ i ] ]--;
    if ( m2[ s2[ i ] ] == 0 ){
        m2.erase( s2[ i ] );
    }
    m2[ s1[ i ] ]++;
    m1[ s2[ i ] ]++;
    if ( max( ( m1.size() ), ( m2.size() ) ) < mn ){
        mn = max( ( m1.size() ), ( m2.size() ) );
    }
    rec( s1, s2, i+1, m1, m2 );
}
```

`mn` is a global variable. What is the time complexity of this recursive function? Let's assume that n (<=20) is taken as input already.n is also global. And also assume that It is called from main with,

rec(s1,s2,0,m1,m2);

My guess is O( logn * 2^n). Is it correct?

Comment: What language is this? It depends on the complexity of `map.erase` and `map.size`.

Comment: Runtime complexity aside, *maintenance time* complexity of this function is downright terrible thanks to a) non-descriptive identifiers and b) zero comments. ;-) (BTW, what is this `n` you speaketh of?)

Comment: I think there is possibly a stackoverflow here, if either `i` or `j` is greater than `n` at the first call. (Which just made me realize, there is no `n`)

Comment: One absolutely sure gets a stack overflow, too, if i and j are not initially equal - independent of whatever n is...

Comment: @Aconcagua you got me, they are always incremented by 1! The next question is, why aren't they a single variable then?

Comment: Calling itself *twice*?

Comment: Please OP be careful with changing the original code you posted, as it makes almost any comment here obsolete and total gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rec` calls itself twice, so if `N == (n-i)`, we can imagine the flow of calls as a binary three of height `N`: `rec` will be called exactly `2^(N+1)-1` times.

`rec` also calls other functions, like `map<...>::size`, `map<...>::operator[]`, `map<...>::erase` etc. The most expensive of these functions should be `O(log M)`, where `M` is the size of the map. They're called sequentially, so we need to only take into account the most expensive of these operations for every call of `rec`.

The final complexity will thus be `O(2^N * log M)`, with `N == (n-i)` and `M == max size of m1 and of m2`

Comment: If `rec` will be called around `2^N` times, shouldn't the complexity be `O(2^N * log M)`?

Comment: @memo1288: whoops, yes! Thanks, just updated the answer.

Comment: @HappyCoder see my last comment in OP's question (it used to be there)

Comment: @ peoro  the equation is  T(n)=6 log n + 2T(n-1) isn't? plz tell me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @sb15: in order to find `O(2^N * log M)` I proceeded in a different way: the way described in the answer. Using the _standard_ approach, yeah, the formula is `T(N) = 2*T(N-1) + log M`. `N` and `M` are what I described in the answer. I'm not exactly sure why you're putting the coefficient `6` in your expression: it's useless and is wrong: there are 8 function calls that cost `O(log M)` (although if you cached the values, they can trivially be optimized out and reduced to 4).

Comment: @sb15 you are incorrect. You should avoid trying to solve recursions by expanding them in your head. peoro used a recursion tree which is the standard way to visualize and solve recursions.

Comment: @ Michael S Priz yah sorry I made a mistake in calculation.

Comment: It actually comes as T(N)= 2^(N-1) * T(1)+ (2^(N-1)-1) log M.